# Function that return array index first value not missing SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, coalesce

I'd like to know some function that return the array index of the first value not missing.

```
data test;
    array A[10];

    do i = 1 to 3;
    A(i) = .;
end;

do i = 4 to 10;
    A(i) = i**2;
end;

fr = coalesce(of A(*));
drop i;
run;
```

Coalesce return the value, in this example 16, but I want a function that return the index, in this case 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using WHICHN()?

```
want = whichn( coalesce(of A(*)), of A(*)) ;
```

You will need to watch out for cases where all of them are missing.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.